# Let $T$ be a bounded operator such that $<Tf,f>=0$ then $T=0?$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a hilbert space. Let $T:H\to H$ be a linear bounded operator such that $<Tf,f>=0$ for all $f\in H$. It is necesarily true that $Tf=0 ?$

When I mean Hilbert space over a field $\mathbb K$ I consider only $\mathbb K= \mathbb C$ or $\mathbb K= \mathbb R$

Comment: That depends on your field.

Comment: Consider rotation by $\pi/2$ is the standard euclidean $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: To be precise: It is true when $\mathbb K = \mathbb C$ and is false when $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$.

Comment: @John I read this lemma:  Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$, and let $T$ be as in the problem. Then $\displaystyle ||T||= \sup_{||f||=1} |<Tf,f>|$  This proves directly this case. But I don't know how to prove it

Comment: @Agumon: You can try to put $f \to f \pm i g$ to get to the equation $\langle T f, g\rangle = 0$ for all $f, g\in H$.